# Putting a picture in wordpress post with python

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to make a post in wordpress that has a photo, but it gives an error

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost
url = 'http://my_website.blog/xmlrpc.php'
username = 'MY_username'
password = 'MY_password'
def send_post(title,content,url_image):
client = Client(url, username, password)
post = WordPressPost()
post.title = title
post.content = content
post.post_status = 'publish'
post.slug = ''
post.thumbnail = url_image
client.call(NewPost(post))
```

Everything works fine, but the picture does not
It gives me this error

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 404: '\u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633\u0647\u0654 
\u067e\u06cc\u0648\u0633\u062a \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0639\u062a\u0628\u0631 
 \u0627\u0633\u062a.'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely with the way you're setting the thumbnail. The `post.thumbnail` expects the ID of the attachment post, not a direct URL. To set a post's thumbnail, you'll first have to upload the image to WordPress and get the attachment ID.

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.media import UploadFile
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client

# Your credentials
url = 'http://my_website.blog/xmlrpc.php'
username = 'MY_username'
password = 'MY_password'

client = Client(url, username, password)

# Define your image and its properties
data = {
    'name': 'filename.jpg',
    'type': 'image/jpeg',  # mimetype
}

# Read the binary file and let the XMLRPC library encode it into base64
with open('path_to_your_image.jpg', 'rb') as img:
    data['bits'] = img.read()

response = client.call(UploadFile(data))
attachment_id = response['id']
```

Now that you have the `attachment_id`, you can use it as the thumbnail for your post

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost

def send_post(title, content, attachment_id):
    post = WordPressPost()
    post.title = title
    post.content = content
    post.post_status = 'publish'
    post.thumbnail = attachment_id
    post_id = client.call(NewPost(post))

# Call the function
send_post("Your Title", "Your Content", attachment_id)
```